# How to subtract two list in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6

Friends, I need help to subtract two list as below, appreciate kind support on this.

```
ListA=['a','b','b','b','c','c','d','e','f','f','g','h']
ListB=['a','b','c','d','e','f','f','g']
```

Answer i need as listC

```
Listc=['b','b','c','h']
```

I tried this with set, but not getting answer as i expected.Tried example as below

```
listC=[set(listA) - set(listB)]
```

Answer of the above example will be

> ['h']

Appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this list comprehension to iterate the list, if the item in `ListB` remove it:

```
>>> ListA=['a','b','b','b','c','c','d','e','f','f','g','h']
>>> ListB=['a','b','c','d','e','f','f','g']
>>>
>>> [i for i in ListA if i not in ListB or ListB.remove(i)]
['b', 'b', 'c', 'h']
```

---

Using a list comprehension doesn't build a list, because of the overhead of creating and extending list, list comprehensions is faster than old loop, the above list comprehension is equivalent to this:

```
r=[]
for i in ListA:
    if i in ListB:
        ListB.remove(i)
    else:
        r.append(i)
print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, this is what I expected, can you give me an idea on how it work. Because i new to the python

Comment: Thanks and really appreciate your well explanation.